# NLog with Xamarin cross-plattform application doesn't log anything

Tags: android, xamarin, logging, nlog

I set up NLog like [this](https://dotnetco.de/logging-in-xamarin-forms-using-nlog/) in the Android part of my Xamarin-project.

My `NLog.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel ="Trace"
      internalLogFile ="C:\Users\MyUser\intLogFile.txt"
      internalLogToConsole="true"
      internalLogIncludeTimestamp ="true">
     <targets>
        <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}" 
            fileName="/storage/emulated/0/Download/${shortdate}.log" />
    </targets>
 
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

- I put the `NLog.config` in the assets-folder in my android-project.
- I added [this NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.7.2?_src=template) to my android-project.
- I changed the build action to `embedded resource`.
- I made sure to have writing permissions on the external storage of the device.
- I am loading the NLog configuration programmatically like [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading) and `nlogConfigFile != null` is true so I assume the `NLog.config` is found.
- As you can see I enabled throwing exceptions from NLog but there are no exceptions thrown...
- ...But the internal logging is not working aswell
- I followed every step of the [troubleshooting by NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting)

Has somebody an idea why NLog is still not logging anything?

--------------------- **UPDATE** ----------------------------

NLog is now logging with basic setup of a LogService-class:

```
 public void Initialize(Assembly assembly, string assemblyName)
    {
       
        var location = $"{assemblyName}.NLog.config";
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(location);
        NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(XmlReader.Create(stream), null);

        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\internalLog.log";

        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogWriter = new StringWriter();

        NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Debug;

    }
```

**But** the internal log is still **not** showing up. As you can see I tried configuring the `InternalLogger` in code and also in the `NLog.config`. I tried putting the `NLog.config` in the `assets`-folder and in the main android-project and I set build action to respectively *embedded ressource* or *android asset*.

--------------------- **2nd UPDATE** --------------------------

The InternalLogger is now working on my Android-device.
In [this tutorial](https://damienaicheh.github.io/xamarin/nlog/2019/06/06/monitor-your-xamarin-application-using-nlog-en.html) the internal file is logged to `c://temp/...` which I assume is a path on Windows. But I am still not able to achieve this during debugging. Is this even possible?

Comment: Which NLog dll are you referencing in your Android project. At the end it says: "If using the NLog.dll built for NetStandard in Xamarin, then the Android assets-folder is not recognized or scanned.`

Comment: @Cheesebaron I am using the .dll from this [NuGet-package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.7.2?_src=template). It says Xamarin Android is supported.

Comment: Right but is the NuGet only added in your core project or also in the Android application project?

Comment: The reference is added to my android project. But you are right I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Is there an internal log? (C:\Users\MyUser\intLogFile.txt"in your case)

Comment: Could you check if `NLog.LogManager.Configuration` is `null`?

Comment: Could you update your question with how you are exactly loading the embedded resource? (Remember you can setup the NLog-InternalLogger at runtime before explicit loading the Nlog.config as embedded resource).

Comment: Right now I am able to log on my android-device. The problem was that the windows-explorer did not update the files on the android-device connected and because of this I did not see the logs. But I am still curious why there is no internal log. @Rolf Kristensen Sure, I'll post an update.

Comment: @Rico227 Any reason why you are using 2 different file-paths? The File-Target points to `/storage/emulated/0/`. Any reason why IinternalLogFile is not using the same path?

Comment: Yes, I wanted the InternalLogFile to be logged on my PC during development. In the meantime I figured out that I am able to log on the android-device if I configure the InternalLogger programmatically. @RolfKristensen

Comment: @Rico227 If your issue has been resolved, then please make an answer to your own question.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Actually it isn't resolved completely. I have posted an update. I'll answer my question with some kind of enhanced troubleshooting soon.

Comment: @Rico227 So when running the application locally using the emulator-environment, then you want to log to some location available from the emulator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following some additional troubleshooting tips that helped me solving my issue:

- If you are using a real Andriod-device and not an emulator unplug the
  debugging connection and reconnect it. The Windows-File-Explorer
  sometimes is not updating the files in the folders of the device if
  it is not reconnected.
- Basic initializing in the code should be enough:

  ```
     public void Initialize(Assembly assembly, string assemblyName)
     {

             var location = $"{assemblyName}.NLog.config";
             var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(location);
             NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(XmlReader.Create(stream), null);
     }
  ```
- You should be fine by putting `NLog.config` as an `embedded resource` in the main folder of the android project. If not put it as an `android asset` in the `assets`-folder.
- If it is still not logging try to set the configuration up [programmatically](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#Configure-NLog-Targets-for-output)
- Also make sure your `minlevel` in the `.config` is lower than the `loglevel` you are using.